# Qt code to get list of files from ftp server using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: qt5

I am writing a simple *FTP client* in **Qt**.
I am using **Qt 5.0**.

I have written a code to download and upload files using `QNetworkAccessManager` as `QFtp` is deprecated from **Qt 5.0**.

I want to write a code to get list of all files on *FTP*.
I got solutions using `QFtp` but not using `QNetworkAccessManager`.
Suggest me how to do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You still need to use `QFtp` if you need to list the content of a remote directory, because `QNetworkAccessManager` doesn't handle that part yet.

`QFtp` has been moved as a standalone module, that you can download or checkout from the gitorious repository: https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtftp (click on "Source tree" then "Download master..." to download).

Comment: Wait - on QFtp deprecation note they say *"However, for new applications, it is recommended to use QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply, as those classes possess a simpler, yet more powerful API."* So powerful it can't even list files? So I guess only alternative to downloading QFtp module is writing the API myself...