# QT QNetworkAccessManager to download file from ftp server not working

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, qnetworkaccessmanager, qnetworkrequest

```
    QNetworkAccessManager *nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    QUrl url2("ftp://127.0.0.1/test.txt/");
    url2.setPassword("12345");
    url2.setUserName("user");
    QNetworkRequest req(url2);


   QNetworkReply *reply = nam->get(req);
   QByteArray data = reply->readAll() ;
   qDebug() << data ;
```

It connects to the local ftp server and reads the file but it gets garbage what am I doing wrong??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111120/qt-code-to-get-list-of-files-from-ftp-server-using-qnetworkaccessmanager   - I haven't heard exactly when they'll get to it either

Answer (score 5):

get() doesn't perform the GET request right away synchronously, but just creates a [QNetworkReply](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html) object, where the actual request will be performed asynchronously at a later point.

`readAll()` reads only the data available at a given time but doesn't block to wait for more data. Right after creation, there isn't any data available.

To wait for all data to be downloaded, connect to the [finished()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html#finished) and [error()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtnetwork/qnetworkreply.html#error-2) signals:

```
connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(requestFinished()));
connect(reply, SIGNAL(error(QNetworkReply::NetworkError)), SLOT(requestError(QNetworkReply::NetworkError));
```

In the `requestFinished()` slot you can then use `readAll()`. That works ok when downloaing small files only. When downloading larger files, better connect to the [readyRead()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qiodevice.html#readyRead) signal and handle the arriving data in incremental chunks instead of using a single `readAll()` in the very end.

Comment: But I'm doing this in main in a simple console app I don't have any classes with slots and signals how would I connect those?

Comment: I would introduce such class(es) then. The alternative are local event loops, the root of many evils.

Comment: I made the class and connected the slot and signal to the object like you told me but I still get garbage when I read the file what am I doing wrong?                                                                         -                                                                            -I get this for output -------->    """"

Comment: I got it to work I checked the error message and aparently it was a permissions issue with the file.