# Qt 5.2.0 ftp and QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, qtnetwork, qftp, qtftp

I need to be able to create directories on my ftp server.

I know that there's no `QFtp` in the 5.2.1 qt, so how do I `mkdir` with `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt code to get list of files from ftp server using QNetworkAccessManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111120/qt-code-to-get-list-of-files-from-ftp-server-using-qnetworkaccessmanager)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QNetworkAccessManager doesn't support that

Comment: Why its been suggested than, to use qnetworkaccessmanager, if it doesn't have all the basic functionality... Anyway i downloaded and compiled the QFtp under vc11.

Answer (score 0):

Although it is recommended to use `QNetworkAccessManager` as much as possible, you always fall back to the `QtFtp` add-on as follows:

```
QT += ftp
```

Then, you will be able to use the mkdir [method](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtftp/source/4e4e73f1007a12a5ab1e035a5ba696d5c07c0e1a%3asrc/qftp/qftp.h#L113) of the `QFtp` class.