# Porting QFtp in Qt4 to Qt5 using QNetworkAccessManager

Tags: c++, qt, ftp, qt5, qnetworkaccessmanager

Instead of `QFtp` in Qt4.8.2 I am now in the process of porting to `QNetworkAccessManager` in Qt5.2.1 etc.

I have the following questions:

1. Is it possible to port `QFtp::rawCommand("SITE UMASK 22");` to a solution based on `QNetworkAccessManager`?
2. How do I specify transfer type using `QNetworkAccessManager`? In `QFtp` it is specified as an argument in e.g. int `QFtp::put(QIODevice* dev,const QString& file,TransferType type = Binary)`?
3. Is it possible to port `int QFtp::rename(const QString & oldname,const QString & newname)` to `QNetworkAccessManager`?

Looking at [Qt code to get list of files from ftp server using QNetworkAccessManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14111120/qt-code-to-get-list-of-files-from-ftp-server-using-qnetworkaccessmanager)
 question on Qt 5.0, makes me think that I need to install the compatibility libraries to make the migration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Qt 5.2.0 ftp and QNetworkAccessManager](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22250898/qt-5-2-0-ftp-and-qnetworkaccessmanager)

Comment: It is either duplicate or broad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The QtFtp library is needed as `QNetworkAccessManager` currently does not support needed functionality. E.g. `QNetworkAccessManager` only use binary transfer mode. In addition, there is no support for any commands other than get and put.

Comment: QtFtp is not actively maintained. It is a good idea to look for some alternative solution, unless you have some legacy code which needs QtFtp. In fact, its readme says: "This repository contains deprecated APIs which have been removed from Qt. Applications are recommended to port to the supported APIs." (https://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtftp.git/tree/readme.txt)