# How is FTP supposed to work with QNetworkAccessManager?

Tags: qt, ftp

So `QFtp` was removed because it had bad design they say. Whatever.

> However, for new applications, it is recommended to use
>   QNetworkAccessManager and QNetworkReply, as those classes possess a
>   simpler, yet more powerful API. (from **[docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qftp.html#details)**)

I looked up `QNetworkAccessManager` and it's just confusing. It's not socket and doesn't even seem to provide raw socket methods. But it's also not FTP. It provides HTTP related functions like `cookieJar`, `post`, `get`... Can someone remind me how does FTP respond to HTTP data?

So this question consists of two parts:

1. What are we basically expected to do to do a simple connection to FTP server and one basic operation, like dir listing.
2. How does it work on low-level, and why.

I have of course found some code and I'm now trying to get it to work, but the real problem is that it makes no sense to me.

Comment: You still need `QFtp` - http://stackoverflow.com/a/14113980/2692481

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Current FTP back-end of `QNetworkAccessManager` implements `get()` and `put()` operations. So, it should be enough to download or to upload files using FTP protocol.

The protocol used by `QNetworkAccessManager` is defined by [URL scheme](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#scheme).
So, for FTP URLs ("ftp://..."), the functions `get()` or `put()` create connection using FTP protocol.

Username and password are taken from `QUrl::userName()` and `QUrl::password()`.

So, the key words in the docs are *"a simpler API"*. It is not needed to execute manually `connect`, `login`, `cd` and `get` commands. Thus, it is not needed to implement own state machine to manage many FTP states in asynchronous application as it was before with [`QFtp`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qftp.html)

`QNetworkAccessManager` provides much simpler API for downloading/uploading files.

For other FTP commands some external module should be used like [`Qt Ftp`](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/admin/projects/qt/qtftp).

Comment: What happens when you call get or put when connected to hhtp aerver?

Comment: @TomášZato If the request URL is started from "http://" the function `get()` works as expected for HTTP protocol. If the URL is started by "ftp://", `get()` will download the required file using FTP protocol.

Comment: @TomášZato In case of FTP, `QNetworkReply` instance also emits signal `metaDataChanged()` once the connection is established. So, it is possible to check file size and date using "Content-Length" and "Last-Modified" header fields (`rawHeaderPairs()`).