# QT C++ - FTP Upload

Tags: c++, qt, ftp

I've got a problem with programming an easy FTP-Upload in QT.
I am currently using QT 5.5 and the QFtp Class is no longer available.
So I used the code that is working in my Visual C++ project.

1. Image: Code from Visual C++
   [image: Code from Visual C++]
2. Image: Code in QT
   [image: Image: Code in QT]
3. Image: Build Error in QT
   [image: Image: Build Error in QT]

Is there a way I can fix this problem? Is it possible to get QFtp working in QT 5.5?

**(string fileToUpload is the file path)**

**(string fileName is the name of the file on the remote machine when it is uploaded)**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please do not post code as images. _Edit_ your question so it includes the code using the correct markdown. Otherwise it can not be searched and also not copy and pasted for others to try and debug the issue.

Comment: I think this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2573834/c-convert-string-or-char-to-wstring-or-wchar-t

Comment: I tried to paste the code into the text field but it didn'T work properly.

Comment: I've embedded it for you, but you could have typed out (or copy and pasted) the code in this case!

Comment: You're welcome. Also note that if you want to refer to someone by name, put an '@' before their name and they'll be notified when you mention them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compilation error is related to conversion of `const char*` to `const wchar_t*`. If you are satisfied with `FtpPutFileW` you can just convert file name to `wchar_t*`. That can be done using Qt `QString`:
[`QString::toWCharArray(wchar_t * array)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toWCharArray) to convert the string to `wchar_t` array (this function does not append null character) or using direct cast:

```
reinterpret_cast<const wchar_t *>(qstring.utf16())
```

Also it possible to use various approaches to conversion of `std::string` to  `wchar_t*`.

If you need just FTP `put` operation the `QNetworkManager` has such function. However, `QNetworkManager` has limited support for low level FTP: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32568786/4023446

So, for other low level FTP commands it is possible to install manually [`Qt FTP`](https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/admin/projects/qt/qtftp).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it out with QNetworkManager but I get the following error: "variable 'QNetworkRequest uploadFile' has initializer but incomplete type
         QNetworkRequest uploadFile(uploadurl);
                                             ^"

Comment: @MasterGrey you need `#include <QNetworkRequest>` and also the qt network module should be added to the project (.pro file `QT +=  network`).

Comment: Thank you very much, that fixed the error. But what is the second parameter for XXX->put(QNetworkRequest, ???)

Comment: @MasterGrey For simplicity you can try the [put version with `QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#put-3) that contains the content to send.

Comment: The program is uploading a file now to the server. But actually the has a size of 0KB. How can I fix this? And how can I specify that the user can choose the file to upload and the name of the file on the remote machine? Thanks in advance! I've createt a QString that contains the text from the TextField.

Comment: @MasterGrey There are too many answers to those questions to fit a comment length. At first you should be confident that you are using `QNetworkAccessManager` properly. The entire content of the `QByteArray` buffer should be uploaded. If you see zero file size it is possible that the upload is not finished. When you call `->put()` the request is only initiated. The `finished()` signal is triggered on finish. Look for some examples.
So, to upload a file you can put its content to such buffer. It is also possible to use `put` version with `QIODevice*`.

Comment: Is this correct?         QString filePath = ui->boxFilePath->text();
        QByteArray file = filePath.toUtf8();

Comment: @MasterGrey No, it is not if you want copy file content to `QByteArray`. It is only file name. You need to open file and read its data. For example, [`QFile f(filePath); f.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); QByteArray data = f.readAll();`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html)

Comment: Ahhh, now it makes sense to me. Thanks very much. I'll try it out.

Comment: Ok, this worked fine for me. Thank you very much, Orest. I think I can make the rest on my own. :)

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the Qt 5.4 documentation, there are add-ons that provide FTP and HTTP streams:

https://forum.qt.io/topic/23904/qtftp-and-qthttp-compatibility-add-ons-for-qhttp-and-qftp-classes-in-qt-5

However, I suggest you start using QNetworkManager to do your FTP & HTTP access. Its interface is more complex (essentially all requests are handled asynchronuously) but when you get the hang of it, it's not so difficult.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The problem is that the links that were posted on the thread are not working.